# Why JPQL ignore parent's fields?

Tags: jpa, jpql

App's stack: `Hibernate`, `Spring Data`, `JPA`.

There are some entities in the app. I try make JPQL-query in repository of my class `OpenParagraph`.

**OpenParagraph**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "open_paragraphs")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class OpenParagraph extends ProgramEntry {

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "sort_num")
    private Integer sortNum;
}
```

`OpenParagraph` has a parent: abstract class `ProgramEntry`.

**ProgramEntry**:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public abstract class ProgramEntry extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "paragraph_id")
    private Paragraph paragraph;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "program_id")
    private Program program;
}
```

So, i tring to appeal to `OpenParagraph`'s field "Paragraph", but IDEA tells me it's mistake:

[image]

It doesn't offer me the "program" field:

[image]

IDEA offer fields only from `OpenParagraph`, not from parent.

**My question**: this is IDEA's fail? If this is'nt IDEA's fail, then how i can call "program" in this query?

Comment: Have you tried to execute the code? What was the result?

Comment: @Lefteris no. I still make services, i can not start the app and can not check

Answer (score 0):

This is/was a bug of Intellij IDEA (maybe related to [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-254740)?). But:

It is possible to query by fields of the super class (or `MappedSuperclass`). Here is an example:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public class Foo extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @Column
    private String fooValue;
    
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Bar extends Foo {

    @Column
    private String barValue;
    
}

public interface BarRepository extends JpaRepository<Bar, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT b FROM Bar b WHERE b.fooValue = ?1")
    List<Bar> findByFooValue(String fooValue);
    
}
```

Given this, calling the repository method, something like this will be logged (with enabled sql logging):

```
Hibernate: select bar0_.id as id1_0_, bar0_.foo_value as foo_valu2_0_, bar0_.bar_value as bar_valu3_0_ from bar bar0_ where bar0_.foo_value=?
```

---

**Hint:**

If you are using Spring Boot (with the test dependency/dependencies and an embedded test db like h2), it is quite easy to execute such methods without to run the whole application. Here just a small snipped that would execute the method (even though this is no test, but that's enough to call methods somehow):

```
@SpringBootTest
public class BarRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    BarRepository barRepository;
    
    @Test
    public void testFindByFooValue() {
        barRepository.findByFooValue("foo");
    }
    
}
```